# How can I add custom shell command in for my project?

Tags: shell-command

In my project, I write scripts to deploy it to server.
Here are the commands:

```
npm run deploy:internal
npm run deploy:staging
npm run deploy:production
```

I want to add custom shell commands to magit, so that I can press `ddi` to run `npm run deploy:internal`, `dds` to run npm run deploy:staging`, and` ddp`to run`npm run deploy:production`.

How can I implement this ?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use Magit to run shell commands which are nothing to do with Git?  That makes little sense to me.

Comment: @phils Because sometimes I want to deploy my project after pushing to git server. I used to switch to iterm2/eshell, and type the commands. This is a bit annoying. So I am finding a way to simplify my workflow.

Comment: Why not use, say, `C-c d [isp]` in the global keymap, and then you can do it from anywhere?

Comment: In any case, that's primarily a matter of which keymap you use.  If you're using a Magit keymap, then you have the problem that `d` invokes the diff popup, and `d d` runs `magit-diff-dwim`, so it seems to me that you've chosen key sequences which are incompatible with your goal.

Comment: @phils I don't care about this. If there is any good choices, I will get it.

Comment: @phils `C-c d [isp]` looks good to me. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to call `shell-command` or `async-shell-command`.

Try this:

```el
(defun my-deploy-internal ()
  "Runs: npm run deploy:internal"
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command "npm run deploy:internal"))

(defun my-deploy-staging ()
  "Runs: npm run deploy:staging"
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command "npm run deploy:staging"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d i") 'my-deploy-internal)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d s") 'my-deploy-staging)
```